# What is the probability that I will be dealt 2 or more diamonds when 5 cards are dealt?

Tags: probability, statistics

So assume we have a standard 52 cards deck that is shuffled fairly. If I am dealt 5 cards what is the probability that I will have 2 or more diamonds?

My initial thought was to add the probability of getting exactly 2, 3, 4, and 5 diamonds. So I did that as follows:

**C(4,1) * C(13, 5) + C(4,1) * C(13, 4) + C(4,1) * C(13, 3) + C(4,1) * C(13, 2)**

But I know that this can't be right because I feel like I am duplicating possibilities. 
Isn't **C(4,1) * C(13, 4)** also including the possibility of getting all 5 diamonds? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Divide the deck into two parts, the diamonds and the non-diamonds. There are $\binom{13}{2}\times \binom{39}{3}$ ways to get exactly two diamonds. Similar for the other cases. The total number of possible deals if $\binom{52}{5}$

Comment: @Peter Ah yeah that makes so much more sense. I was able to calculate the rest and it was right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following PARI/GP-programs calculates the exact probability and the
 numerical representation. The chance is about $36,7\%$.

```
? sum(j=2,5,binomial(13,j)*binomial(39,5-j)/binomial(52,5))
%2 = 1223/3332
? sum(j=2,5,binomial(13,j)*binomial(39,5-j)/binomial(52,5))*1.0
%3 = 0.3670468187274909963985594238
```